# Run celery task for specific time period

Tags: django, celery

I'm developing web app using django, and I'm using celery to run task in background. Everything is working fine, But i have one issue, I want to run celery task for the specific time period
like from 2pm to 3pm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you're using Celery beat to run periodic tasks. Your requirement should be possible using [Crontab schedule](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules). Specifically following this example that's given there:

> `crontab(minute=0, hour='*/3,8-17')`
>
> Execute every hour divisible by 3, and every hour during office hours (8am-5pm).

**EDIT:** If you want to run the task only once but want to specify the time when it's going to be started, specify [ETA](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) when calling the task. Example from the documentation:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> tomorrow = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=1)
>>> add.apply_async((2, 2), eta=tomorrow)
```

Comment: I didn't want to run task in interval, I just want to run task once, date specified by the user

Comment: @SandeepPrasadKushwaha See the updated answer please.